# Accept multiple values on proc macro attribute

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I wanted to be able to retrieve the content from an attribute like this:

`#[foreign_key(table = "some_table", column = "some_column")]`

This is how I am trying:

```
impl TryFrom<&&Attribute> for EntityFieldAnnotation {
    type Error = syn::Error;

    fn try_from(attribute: &&Attribute) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if attribute.path.is_ident("foreign_key") {
            match attribute.parse_args()? {
                syn::Meta::NameValue(nv) => 
                    println!("NAME VALUE: {:?}, {:?}, {:?}", 
                        nv.path.get_ident(), 
                        nv.eq_token.to_token_stream(),
                        nv.lit.to_token_stream(),
                    ),
                _ => println!("Not interesting")
            }
        } else {
            println!("No foreign key")
        }

    // ... More Rust code
}
```

Everything works fine if I just put in there only one `NameValue`. When I add the comma,
everything brokes.

The only error:
`error: unexpected token`

How can I fix my logic to enable the possibility of have more than just one `NameValue`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: While writing this answer, I had forgotten that `Meta` has `List` variant as well which gives you `NestedMeta`. I would generally prefer doing that instead of what I did in the answer below for more flexibility.

Although, for your particular case, using `Punctuated` still seems simpler and cleaner to me.

---

`MetaNameValue` represents only a single name-value pair. In your case it is delimited by `,`, so, you need to parse all of those delimited values as `MetaNameValue` instead.

Instead of calling `parse_args`, you can use [parse_args_with](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.Attribute.html#method.parse_args_with) along with [Punctuated::parse_terminated](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/punctuated/struct.Punctuated.html#method.parse_terminated):

```rust
use syn::{punctuated::Punctuated, MetaNameValue, Token};

let name_values: Punctuated<MetaNameValue, Token![,]> = attribute.parse_args_with(Punctuated::parse_terminated).unwrap(); // handle error instead of unwrap
```

Above `name_values` has type [Punctuated](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/punctuated/struct.Punctuated.html#) which is an iterator. You can iterate over it to get various `MetaNameValue` in your attribute.

---

**Updates based on comments**:

Getting value out as `String` from `MetaNameValue`:

```rust
let name_values: Result<Punctuated<MetaNameValue, Token![,]>, _> = attr.parse_args_with(Punctuated::parse_terminated);

match name_values {
    Ok(name_value) => {
        for nv in name_value {
            println!("Meta NV: {:?}", nv.path.get_ident());
            let value = match nv.lit {
                syn::Lit::Str(v) => v.value(),
                _ => panic!("expeced a string value"), // handle this err and don't panic
            };
            println!( "Meta VALUE: {:?}", value )
        }
    },
    Err(_) => todo!(),
};
```

Comment: Works fine, but I am struggling getting the value in the `MetaNameValue`. Can you help?

Comment: Mhmm, `meta_name_value.lit` should give you the value. Can you be more specific about what are you struggling with?

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling on how to get an `&str` from the `meta_name_value.lit`

Comment: Try to follow docs on [MetaNameValue](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.MetaNameValue.html). Type of `lit` is `Lit`. Go to doc of `Lit` and you will see it is an enum which has a variant [`Lit::Str`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Lit.html#variant.Str). Match for that variant and you will get [`LitStr`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.LitStr.html). `LitStr` has a method called [`LitStr::value`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.LitStr.html#method.value) which will give you a `String`.

Comment: That's the exact part of where I am struggling. I am matching the LitStr(v) and getting `expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found function `syn::Lit`
not a tuple struct or tuple variant`

I am not understanding something, or maybe I should stop until tomorrow (rofl).

Comment: This is what I am trying: 
```
match name_values {
            Ok(name_value) => {
                for nv in name_value {
                    println!("Meta NV: {:?}", nv.path.get_ident());
                    let value: &str = match nv.lit {
                        syn::LitStr(v) => v.value() 
                    };
                    println!(
                        "Meta VALUE: {:?}", value
                    )
                }
            },
            Err(_) => todo!(),
        }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to fix the snippet. Seems like you are tired and making silly mistakes, get a good night sleep :).

Comment: This `LitStr` instead of `Lit::Str`. The tiredness is real.
Thanks for your kind words an response :)